# Naming ArrayLists from user input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, user-input

After much research, I can't find anything on this,
Is it even possible to generate an Array list entirely from user input,
populating the list is easy, but I want to name the Array from user input also,

```
List<String> jTextfield.getText = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now i know this won't work, but is something to this effect even possible?

Comment: Just curious why do you want Arraylist Name to be from the user input ?

Comment: This is not possible in Java, and, moreover, should *not* be used even in languages where it is possible. It involves evaluating user input as code. Now, if you're thinking about *attaching a name* to a list that a user provides, that's easy: use `Map<String, List<String>>`. Store the name of the user-provided list as the key, and the list itself as the value.